# Add a border to circle image

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a circle image. Now I want to add a border red color with 2px or 3px width around it. How can I do that with PHP script?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use the imageline function...

```
function imagecircle($source,$r,$x,$y,$color){
  for($i = 0;$i<=2*pi();$i+=(pi()/180)){
    imageline($source,cos($i)*$r+$x,sin($i)*$r+$y,
      cos($i+(pi()/180))*$r+$x,sin($i+(pi()/180))*$r+$y,$color);
  }
}
```

$source is the image you want to draw on, either created with gd or loaded and instantiated with gd like this:

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg('imgname.jpg');